# obtain gcc-6-cross for u-boot making on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cross-compilation

Try to build RPi 3 u-boot, but it required cross compiler aarch64-linux-gun-gcc to be version 6 or later. On Ubuntu 16.04, it's version 5. 
Find gcc-6-cross source but has not much knowledge or experience to build it up. Could anybody show me some clues about how to achieve this? Thanks